# Simple practice proof

Tags: number-theory

I am still trying to master the notion of proofs. It is quite a difficult transition, and I am not the best at it. Any suggestions or corrections on my logic would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Claim: If $n$ is an integer, then $n^2 \geq n$.

I rewrote this as:
For all integers $n$, $n^2 \geq n$.

Proof: Suppose $n^2$ < $n$, for all integers $n$. Then, $n \cdot n < n \implies n < 1$. This is not true since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ can also be greater than or equal to $1$. Thus, contradicting our assumption.

I feel like I completely butchered this proof, but I am just starting to practice it more. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the need for proof by contradiction.

Comment: If you do a proof by contradiction (not recommended, but that seems to be how you are starting), the negation of: 'For all integers $n$, $n^2>n$' is not 'For all integers $n$, $n^2<n$' ; but rather: 'There exists an integer $n$ such that $n^2<n$.  That is, the negation of a universal statement (for all), is an existential statement (there exists)..

Comment: Thanks. Would a direct proof be adequate? If so, how do I go about it? Intuitively, I can look at the claim and know it is true, but writing it in proof format is the hard part.

Comment: Both direct and indirect have the same principal.  If $n \ge 1$ then $n*n \ge n*1$ and that works whether you divide to go from $n^2 < n \implies n < 1$ which is a contradiction or if you go from $n \ge 1 \implies n^2 \ge n$.  But what would you do if some pick pendant (like me) comes along and asks "Why do you say $n\cdot n < n$ would imply $n < 1$?  Why do you claim that? How do you know it is true?"  Would you have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** $n^2\geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If there is even a **single** counterexample, then we know that the claim is false. So in fact, the true negation of the claim is:
Suppose $n^2<n$ for **some** $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The rest of the proof follows like this:

If $n^2<n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $n^2-n<0\implies n(n-1)<0$. 
Consider the following three cases:

$1)$ If $n=0$, then $n(n-1)=0\nless0$ so we arrive at a contradiction.

$2)$ If $n>0$, then $n-1\geq 0$ so $n(n-1)\nless 0$ and we arrive at a contradiction.

$3)$ If $n<0$, then $n-1<0$ so $n(n-1)>0$ and we arrive at a contradiction.

QED

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down so easily for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The negation of "for all" is "there exists". If you want to proceed solving this question with a proof by contradiction, your starting assumption must be "Suppose $n^2<n$ for *some* integer $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then, your need to be a little more careful in the writing of the proof. Indeed, you are trying to divide your inequality by $n$ to deduce a contradiction, but there are two things you need to be attentive to. First, $n$ must not be zero. The case $n=0$, which is trivial, must be mentioned separatedly. Second, if $n$ is negative, then the order of the inequality changes. So you need to treat the cases $n$ positive and $n$ negative separatedly (and conclude as you did).

Now, because of these cases that need to be distinguished, this kind of proof is not recommended.

You may show the result directly, by noticing that $n^2 \geq n$ if and only if $n(n-1)\geq 0$. A product of two quantities is non-negative if and only if both have the same sign. Thus, you are reduced to proving that for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n$ and $n-1$ have the same sign (with the meaning "both are non-negative or both are non-positive"). This is now rather straightforward.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine, after the modification in the comments. However, you can do a direct proof also:

Let $n$ be any integer. Thus $n \ge 1$. Multiplying this inequality* with $n \ge n$ we get $n^2 \ge n$.

*In the definition of $\ge$ it is said that if $a \ge b$ and $c \ge d$, and all quantities are positive, then $ac \ge bd$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome!